# Receiving 404 Error accessing phpmyadmin on Jetware LEMP AMI

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, amazon-rds

I am receiving the following errors when attempting to access phpmyadmin on our machine based of the Jetware WordPress 4 on LEMP 7 Max Performance. I have changed the php phpmyadmin/config.inc.php file to point to our RDS instance. Then restarted the server.

> 2018/01/28 17:58:21 [error] 15187#0: *25685 open() "/jet/app/wordpress404" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 46.246.63.236, server: _, request: "GET //MyAdmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1", host:
>
> 2018/01/28 17:58:20 [error] 15187#0: *25683 open() "/jet/app/wordpress404" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 46.246.63.236, server: _, request: "GET //pma/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1", host:
>
> 2018/01/28 17:58:18 [error] 15187#0: *25681 open() "/jet/app/wordpress404" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 46.246.63.236, server: _, request: "GET //phpMyAdmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1", host:

## jetware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received an email from Jetware support. The issue was apparently that i was not ending the url with /.

> Hi Rick, try to append the slash '/' at the end of the URL, i.e.
>   http://xxx/phpmyadmin/